# Weird issue with jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a weird bug with jQuery.

You can see in my HTML I have an input with the id `checkbx`, and in my javascript I have a selector targeting something with the id `checkbox`.

Now, all of this works, despite the fact that the jQuery seems to be selecting a nonexistant id.

The issue came when I tried to fix this error, either by changing the selector to `checkbx` or the id to `checkbox`, when i did this, the first click on the checkbox does not register, which messes up the coloring of the words.

My question is, why is this happening and how do i fix it.

This is my code.

```js
function checkbox() {
var $y = $("#yon");
var $n = $("#non");
var $cx = $("#chex")
var $cbx = $("#checkbox");
var chval = false;
$(".cspan").click(function() {
 $n.toggleClass("no");
 $y.toggleClass("yes");
 if (chval) {
  $cx.text("\u2716");
  $cbx.prop('checked', false);
  chval = false;
 }
 else {
  $cx.text("\u2714");
  $cbx.prop('checked', true);
  chval = true;
 }
});
}
$(function() {
    checkbox();
});
```

```css
.checkbx{
display:none;
}
.checkbx + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 170px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 25px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
 position:absolute;
 background-color: #ff3a31;
 transition: background-color 100ms linear;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.checkbx:checked + label span {
    background-color: #00cc66;
    transition: background-color 100ms linear;
}
.checkemb{
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-left:10px;
 font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
 color:#ffffff;
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
p.xy{
 margin-right:25px;
 margin-left:25px;
}
p.yes{
 color:#990800;
 transition: color 100ms linear;
}
p.no{
 color:#008040;
 transition: color 100ms linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Checkbox test-css.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Checkbox test-js.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="checkcon">
   <input id="checkbx" class="checkbx" type="checkbox"/>
   <label for="checkbx">
    <span class="cspan">
     <p class="checkemb yes" id="yon">Yes</p>
     <p class="checkemb xy" id="chex"><strong>&#10006;</strong></p>
     <p class="checkemb" id="non">No</p>  
    </span>
   </label>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The ID of your element in the HTML is `checkbx`. You're missing an `o`.

Comment: I know that, fixing it is what causes the problem.

Comment: You've got that clickable text inside a `<label>` that's targetted at the checkbox `<input>`. That means that clicks on the label will already toggle the value of the checkbox without JavaScript.

Comment: The reason for the javascript is because  need to: swap the charactor in the middle from an X to a checkmark.

Comment: Right, but you do not need to update the "checked" property; the browser will do that for you. (You could probably do the whole thing with just CSS too, using the `:checked` pseudo-class.)

Comment: I guess you're right. That code used to be necessary but isn't now. some things, like the character swapping may still need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/kj50soov/1/

```
function checkbox() {
var $y = $("#yon");
var $n = $("#non");
var $cx = $("#chex")
var $cbx = $("#checkbx");
var chval = false;
$(".cspan").click(function() {
    $n.toggleClass("no");
    $y.toggleClass("yes");
    if (chval) {
        $cx.text("\u2716");
        chval = false;
    }
    else {
        $cx.text("\u2714");
        chval = true;
    }
});
}
$(function() {
    checkbox();
});
```

Like Pointy said you don't need to manually set the checked property. Also jQuery won't throw any errors or anything if you select a bogus id, so it wasn't "working" in the first place.

Comment: That should work, i was just confused why FIXING the id caused it to break

Comment: I think it's because once you fixed the id, the code that manually set the `checked` property started working. And bcuz the browser checks the box for you when you click it's `label`, the property was being set twice, incorrectly.